# How to remove the contents of a string after the first occurrence of a character in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a set of strings with each string containing letters, numbers & symbols. I would like to extract the contents of a string until the occurrence of a number & preceding symbol. Here is an example:

```
Axis-1.4.5
Limo_9.5.6R
Dent-ist-0C.4E
Log4M-1.2.0
Hello-World-1.0
```

These are my strings. What I want from this as my output is:

```
Axis
Limo
Dent-ist
Log4M
Hello-World
```

I used the patterns **replaceAll("\d","")** & **replaceAll("[-+.^:,_]","")** to remove the numbers and the symbols. But what I got as my outpus with this is:

```
Axis
LimoR
DentistCE
LogM
HelloWorld
```

Could someone please let me know how to trim the string properly for this scenario?

Comment: Should "Dentist" really be "Dent-ist"? (Or should "Hello-World" really be "HelloWorld"?)

Comment: Dentist should be Dent-ist. Have the changed it in the post as well

Comment: Basically, I am expecting the symbols occurring between letters to come and the symbols preceding numbers to be gone along with the numbers and any letters successive to numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `replaceFirst("[-+.^:,_]\d.*", "")` should do what you want.

You can read that as "a 'symbol' followed by a digit followed by everything else in the string."

Comment: Given the original request, `".\d.*"` is better pattern.

Comment: @bezmax That would turn "Log4M-1.2.0" into "Lo", while the desired output is "Log4M". The description in the question was "a number and a preceding symbol." Reading between the lines, I think a "symbol" here means a hyphen, underscore, etc. I used the character class the original questioner used.